# Diff between dirty file in editor memory and version saved to disk in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Frequently I leave files open for many days to the point I forget they were even open, and many times these files have changes that aren't persisted in the history because I've reboot in between.

Is there a plugin or command I can use to see the diff between what I have in front of me and what's on the disk? I don't want to copy->paste->save->diff. I'm looking for something like the version control integration with the green and red lines, the pluses/minuses, and whiz bangs.

Comment: Does the [Compare action](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_preventing-dirty-writes) help here?

Comment: Thanks, it's very very close, except in the case of the link you provided, the file is edited elsewhere.